# Manually updating software, installed via GPO, results in two versions installed

Tags: windows, group-policy, installation, msi

Notebook received a software package version 1 via GPO from a network share. Then v2 of the same application was installed manually on that computer. Installer removed old v1.

Several days later, when notebook was off the network, user attempted to install v3. Installation failed, saying that old version cannot be removed. Installer logs says that setup found v2 and v1 installed and tried to removed them both before v3 installation, but could not remove v1, because it's setup was on network share that is currently not available.

Is it possible that v1 got somehow registered by GPO as "installed" even after it was uninstalled and upgraded to v2?

Comment: Yes, because GPO doesn't know that the user manually upgraded to version 2 and uninstalled version 1. If you're going to deploy software with GPO then it's all or nothing. GPO has to fully "manage" the lifecycle of that software. You can't have your cake and eat it too. My suggestion would be to redeploy version 1 with GPO, then use GPO to upgrade to whatever version you like. - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783421(v=ws.10).aspx - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816102#method5

Comment: All versions had the same MSI UpgradeCode, so i thought GPO would notice that, however doesn't look like it did.